# CakePHP 3.0 retrieving record from database

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im trying to get client name from database but there is error that says 
"Trying to get property of non-object "

code line in index looks like this

```
 $this->Html->link( $camp->client->name,['controller' => 'Clients', 'action' => 'view', $camp->id]);
```

this is controller

```
public function index($id = null) {
    $client = $this->Camps->Clients->find()->where(['Clients.id' => $camp['client_id']])->first();
    debug($client);
    if ($id != null) {
        $query = $this->Camps->find('all')->where(['client_id' => $id]);
        $this->set('camps', $this->paginate($query));
        $client = $this->Camps->Clients->get($id);
    } else {
        $query = $this->Camps->find('all');
        $this->set('camps', $this->paginate($query));
        $client = $this->Camps->Clients->find('all')->toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put <?php print_r($camp); ?> before the the link and post the output.

Comment: @blur0224 You'd better use/recommend `debug()`... `print_r()` will output nothing for `null`, `false`, empty strings, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I guess that you want to get the camps with their client. So you have to use `contain(['Clients])` in your find

Comment: you not pass $camp['client_id'] to function, only `$id`